# Aplicar bordes en un polígono con CSS

Tags: css, styled-components

Necesito lograr esta figura con los bordes idénticos a la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi styled component:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 30%;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #E71383;
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), rgba(94, 8, 53, 0.5);
clip-path: polygon(0 15px, 15px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

Pero el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, recuerda adjuntar tu intento para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y recibas respuestas cuanto antes, mira [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Posiblemente tengas un resultado similar con este [generador](https://unused-css.com/tools/clip-path-generator).

Comment: Tu respuesta está excelente, solo que necesito dar color a cada uno de los bordes, incluso el recortado

Comment: Y qué has intentado?

Comment: Aquí hay [varios ejemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style) de cómo hacerlo (más optaría por [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44331414/17727129)), saludos.

Comment: Ya actualicé la publicación, mi resultado está bien, solo que no se aplica el borde a la esquina recortada

Comment: El borde no se puede aplicar a un polígono hecho con `clip-path`. Una solución es usar un contenedor al que le aplicas también `clip-path` y que su `background-color` sea igual que el color de borde del hijo, lo dispones de tal forma que ese pedacito de fondo del contenedor parezca el borde de la esquina que buscas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras puedes enviar un ejemplo en código? Por favor

Answer (score 0):

Buenas me pareció interesante así que lo decidí revisar. Después de intentar un rato darle un borde conseguí esto, espero que te ayude, si es que todavía no lo haz resuelto.

- Primero agregar el position relative al poligono que ya tenias

```css
.poligon {
    position: relative; /* Para que funcione debes agregar*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #E71383;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), rgba(94, 8, 53, 0.5);
    clip-path: polygon(0 12px, 10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
/* Hice una pequeña modificación al poligono*/
  }
```

Ahora haciendo uso de la pseudo clase before, genero un cuadrado en la esquina superior izquierda y luego al jugar con las propiedades "border-width", "top", "width", "height" y "left", puedes conseguir un resultado bastante semejante

```css
  .poligon::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    left: 0;
    border-width: 9px 9px 2px 4px;
    border-color: #E71383 transparent transparent #E71383;
  }
```

Una muestra de como me quedo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve un rato dándole vueltas pero a partir de esto puedes seguir modificando para mejorar el resultado por supuesto , en si la solución esta en la pseudo clase before

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, esta respuesto me ayudó a solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0):

Sin lugar a dudas la forma más fácil es usar una imagen png o svg.

Yo me iré por el camino dificil, para ello usaré el API de `paintWorklet`

Paso 1: Crear un archivo "border-radius.js"

Este código creará 2 imagenes:

- Una imagen para el borde -> la usaremos en el background
- Otra para el fondo -> la usaremos como mascara con -webkit-mask-image

```
class Border {
    Dibujar(ctx,w,h) {
        const factorX =w / 100;
        const factorY = h / 100;
        const X = num => factorX * num;
        const Y = num => factorY * num;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, Y(100)); // (1)
        ctx.lineTo(0, Y(70));// (2)
        ctx.lineTo(Y(70), 0);// (3)
        ctx.lineTo(X(100), 0);// (4)
        ctx.lineTo(X(100), Y(100));// (5)
        ctx.closePath();

        //las funciones X e Y, convierten a porcentaje
        //ej: X(70) se refiere al una linea de largo 70% con respecto al ancho

        // Recordar que el punto 0,0 es el de la izquierda arriba. X aumenta hacia la derecha e Y hacia abajo

        //  (3)___________(4)
        //    /           |
        //(2)/            |
        //   |            |
        //   |____________|(5)
        //  (1)

    }
}
class BorderRadiusPainter extends Border {
    static get inputProperties() {
        return ['--border-width', '--border-color']
    }


    paint(ctx, geom, props) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = props.get('--border-color');
        ctx.lineWidth = Number(props.get('--border-width'));;
        this.Dibujar(ctx,geom.width, geom.height)
        ctx.stroke();
        
    }
}

class BorderRadiusMask extends Border {
    paint(ctx, geom, props) {
        this.Dibujar(ctx, geom.width, geom.height)
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
registerPaint('border-radius', BorderRadiusPainter);
registerPaint('border-radius-mask', BorderRadiusMask);
```

Paso 2: Cargar el script dentro del HTML

```
    <script>
        CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('border-radius.js');
    </script>
```

Paso 3: Agregar los CSS

```
.pestana{
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color:white;
    align-items: center;
    --border-width:2;
    --border-color:#E71383;
    -webkit-mask-image:  paint(border-radius-mask);
    background:paint(border-radius), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), rgba(94, 8, 53, 0.5);         
}
```

Aquí usamos las 2 imagenes que se generan con javascript

- -webkit-mask-image:  paint(border-radius-mask);
- background: paint(border-radius), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), rgba(94, 8, 53, 0.5);

Además, podemos variar el grosor del borde y su color directamente desde el css  modificando las variables:

- --border-width
- --border-color

Paso 4: agregar el HTML

```
<div class="pestana">sadasd</div>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está sumamente interesante tu respuesta, el resultado es genial. Lo pondré a prueba, muchas gracias!